# How to compile a Servlet class?

Tags: java, api, tomcat, servlets, server

How can i compile a servlet class?
I set up the environment for tomcat on mac, I startup tomcat server and now I would make my own server.

I start writing helloWorld class that extends HttpServlet.

I downloaded server-api.jar, I have to put it in a particular folder?

Now, how can I compile my servlet class hello world? Thank you very much.